# How to get responseObject into cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm making an 'Add Friend' function, where it's possible to search on a username. I have a `responeObject` that contains an array of users. I only want to get the `@"name"` object for all the users and then list them in the TableView. If I search on "e" i get 3 results:

```
responseObject: (
    {
    id = 1;
    isUsersAccount = 0;
    name = Eshixf;
},
    {
    id = 3;
    isUsersAccount = 0;
    name = Neigstal;
},
    {
    id = 4;
    isUsersAccount = 0;
    name = Howie;
})
```

How can I get out all 3 names in 3 different cells?
And why does I get an error when I running the code with this line inside?:

```
NSDictionary *nameDict = [[friendRow objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

It gives me this error:

> -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faec35f4d40

Thank you!

Comment: `[friendRow objectAtIndex:0]` returns `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`. And even if it returns `NSDictionary` when you call `objectForKey:` this will return `NSString`. By the way what is `friendRow`?

Comment: @meth sry, it is:
`friendRow = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseObject, nil];`

Comment: But I can get out the name of the first object/item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all names with simple iteration over response.

```
NSArray *response = friendRow[0]; // this is result dictionaries in an array. actually it is your responseObject.

//NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray new];
names = [NSMutableArray new];//if declared outside the method, use this array as a dataSource for tableView.
for(NSDictionary *dict in response)
{
     [names addObject:dict[@"name"]];
}
NSLog("names %@", names);

//refresh your tableview;
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

EDIT for TableView:

create names in interface as

```
NSMutableArray *names;
```

in delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:names[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

with this method, tableview will know how many cells it needs.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [names count];
}
```

Comment: Nvm, i guess it should be `in response` instead of `names` ;)!

Comment: yes i changed it immediately after posting answer:) sorry for that.

Comment: Np! And ty for help :) 1 last thing - how do I get these values into the cell.textLabel? I think this TableView stuff is kinda confusing :/@meth

Comment: you should make changes on tableview's datasource with this names. But if you dont have enough information about `UITableView`, you can find a lot of tutorial over internet.

Comment: Ye i know, but i can't seem to find someone that was so helpful. But I do know a bit, and what I have now in textlabel is:
`cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username %@", indexPath.row];`

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username %@", names[indexPath.row]];` will solve your problem. but dont forget to define `names` in interface. so that you can reach it from everywhere

Comment: Why should that work? Now does it just say "Username: and 'name'" in the first cell

Comment: When I do that it says "Local declaration of 'names' hides instance variable

Comment: I've tried this in a lots of ways now, and it simply just don't wanna work for me... The thing in the delegate method doesn't work for me. Neither does 'return [names count];.. Then there's nothing in the cell@meth

Comment: did you set `tableView.delegate = self;` and `tableView.dataSource = self;` and add `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. if these doesnt help, you have another problems. @MarckJensen

Comment: I have:
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return 1;
}`

Comment: second one must be `return [names count]`

Comment: Then nothing shows..
I also have:
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
NSArray *response = friendRow[0];
for (NSDictionary *dict in response) {
        [names addObject:dict[@"name"]];
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
`

Comment: you should really read about `UITableView`. Because there are serious problems with your structure using `UITableView`. just give your 1 hour [to this tutorial](http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/). this will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, and ty for your help :-)